# Why is the fundamental group of a closed hyperbolic $n$-manifold is a (uniform) lattice in $SO(n,1)$?

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, geometric-topology, fundamental-groups

Why is the fundamental group of a closed hyperbolic $n$-manifold is a (uniform) lattice in $SO(n,1)$? Why is $SO(n,1)$ the (orientation-preserving) isometry group of real hyperbolic
$n$-space?

Is there any reference for a proof?

Comment: That is the group of congruence transformations of hyperbolic $n$-space. Since the geometric structure is complete the deck transformations are a discrete subgroup of $SO(n,1)$.

Comment: For dimension $3$ download Thurston’s notes from MSRI.